# Apache2 get 403 error when get Django project's static css file

Tags: django, apache, static, http-status-code-403

I am a very newbie to Django and I just finished the 1st Tutorial (which is a poll website). Now I run it with

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

and everything works fine. Now I am trying to deploy this project with apache2 and mod_wsgi, and I have tried the same documents, but how hard I have tried, I can't make the apache2 to access my static css file, even thought the django contents works fine (including access the DB file).

here is my django site conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName localhost

         Alias /static/ /home/coeus/projects/django/mysite/polls/static/
         <Directory /home/coeus/projects/django/mysite/mysite/static>
         Require all granted
         </Directory>

         WSGIScriptAlias / /home/coeus/projects/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

         <Directory /home/coeus/projects/django/mysite/mysite>
         <Files wsgi.py>
         Require all granted
         </Files>
         </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried to set the ownership for "mysite" to www-data:www-data, but it not help.

the Apache's access.log shows below:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2015:16:18:40 +0800] "GET /static/polls/style.css HTTP/1.1" 403 522 "http://127.0.0.1/polls/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36"
```

I am totally stuck here...

Please help. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What I have done was store my static files on public_dir where your index.fcgi and .htaccess lives and maybe in a folder 'static' then all you need to do is point to that folder from your html

`<img src="/static/images/love.png" />
or
<img src="http://mydoman.me/static/images/love.png" />`

It works fine from my side

Comment: All am saying is you should try pointing to the files as if you would if they were on a different server, like use full path name or something

Comment: Finally i solved - there is a typo above, when i changed, everything works fine.:)